# python importlib no module named

Tags: python, flask, python-importlib

I am using flask and have the following structure

```
<root>
manage_server.py
cas <directory>
--- __init__.py
--- routes.py
--- models.py
--- templates <directory>
--- static <directory>
--- formmodules <directory>
------ __init__.py
------ BaseFormModule.py
------ Interview.py
```

In routes.py, I'm trying to create an instance of the Interview class in the Interview module, like so

```
my_module = "Interview"
module = importlib.import_module('formmodules."+my_module)
```

I get an error here that says

```
ImportError: No module named formmodules.Interview
```

Some info about the init files:

```
/cas/formmodules/__init__.py is empty
/cas/__init__.py is where I initialize my flask app.
```

Let me know if it is helpful to know the contents of any of these files.

Comment: Is `formmodules` a subdirectory of `cas` or not?

Comment: yes, formodules is a subdirectory of cas

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is one of the classical relative vs absolute import problems.

`formmodules` only exists relative to `cas`, but `import_module` does an absolute import (as with [`from __future__ import absolute_imports`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/)). Since `formmodules` cannot be found via `sys.path`, the import fails.

One way to fix this is to use a [relative import](https://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html#module-importlib).

> If the name is specified in relative terms, then the package argument must be specified to the package which is to act as the anchor for resolving the package name.

You might want to try with:

```
module = importlib.import_module('.formmodules.' + my_module, package=__package__)
```

Note the `.`.

The other option is to muck about with `sys.path`, which really isn't necessary, here.

Comment: I almost missed the leading period. Works great!